# Angular JS Animation with ng-show not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a angular app where i am using animation in ng-show attribute on button click to show and hide a div element .It works fine in the hide case but it does not work fine in show case it immediately shows the element without the animation.You can see the same behavior in the example 
:http://yearofmoo-articles.github.io/angularjs-animation-article/app/#/ng-show-hide .

My Code is

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                        <button class="btn btn-large btn-success pull-right" type="button" ng-click="showtravelSchedule=!showtravelSchedule">Search</button>
                   </div>

    <div class=" span3 module offset1 community-bulletin" ng-show="showtravelSchedule" ng-animate="{show: 'example-show', hide: 'example-hide'}">
    </div>
```

and css is

```
.example-show, .example-hide {
-webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
-moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
-ms-transition:all linear 0.5s;
-o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.example-show {
opacity:0;
}
.example-show.example-show-active {
opacity:1;
}

.example-hide {
opacity:1;
}
.example-hide.example-hide-active {
opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored it a bit, and it seems to be working with this setup:

```
    .example-show, .example-hide {
        -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
        -moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
        -ms-transition:all linear 0.5s;
        -o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
        transition:all linear 0.5s;
    }

    .example-show.example-show-active,
    .example-hide {
        opacity:1;
    }

    .example-hide.example-hide-active,
    .example-show {
        opacity:0;
    }
```

Not sure why it makes a difference.